# Decode base64 file to directory in Ionic 3 App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, base64, decode

I make an endpoint request that returns me the code for the file. This could be an image for example, although I can display passing the binary code directly to the img src, I would like to save the file in the application directory so that the user does not have to spend mobile data again to view the image. Is it possible to do this on Ionic 3?

Kind of how this Ionic plugin works: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64-to-gallery

The point is, I need one that downloads any kind of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago, i've created this

```
 var base64;
  var dataTypeWithB64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64; 

  public writeFile(dataTypeWithB64: any, base64:any,) {  
  var fileName ="file Name";
  var rootPath = "app path"

  var contentType = this.getContentType(dataTypeWithB64); 
  // var content
  var DataBlob = this.base64toBlob(base64, contentType);  
  // here iam mentioned this line this.file.externalRootDirectory is a native pre-defined file path storage. You can change a file path whatever pre-defined method.  
  var filePath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + rootPath;
  console.log(filePath , " 1");
  console.log(fileName , " 2");
  console.log(DataBlob , " 3");
  console.log(contentType , " 4");

  this.file.writeFile(filePath, fileName, DataBlob, contentType).then((success) => {  
      console.log("File Writed Successfully", success);  
  }).catch((err) => {  
      console.log("Error Occured While Writing File", err);  
  })  
}  
//here is the method is used to get content type of an bas64 data  
public getContentType(base64Data: any) {  
  let block = base64Data.split(";");  
  let contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];  
  return contentType;  
}  
//here is the method is used to convert base64 data to blob data  
base64toBlob(b64Data, contentType) {  
  contentType = contentType || '';  
  let sliceSize = 512;

  let byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);  
  let byteArrays = [];  
  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {  
      let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);  
      let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);  
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {  
          byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);  
      }  
      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);  
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);  
  }  
  let blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {  
      type: contentType  
  });  
  // console.log(blob) 
  return blob; 
}
```